# Is it possible to use the range function in Azure Data Factory and add ID's to the result?

Tags: arrays, range, azure-data-factory

Let's say I want to use the `range` function (inside a ForEach loop) in Azure Data Factory to create an array which consists of integers. These integers represent API pages related to some ID which was given to us as a parameter in the ForEach loop.

I would use it like `@range(1, int(varMaxApiPages))`.
This gives me what I expect; an array of integers:
`[1, 2, 3]`

But would it be possible to append the related ID to these integers? So the result would be something like: `[{"someID", 1},{"someID", 2},{"someID", 3}]`?

Comment: We can use append activity in ADF to do that.

Comment: How do you know that 1="someID"?

Comment: It all relates to the same ID (which is input for the ForEach loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such as:

```py
def appendToArray(varMaxApiPages):
    arr1 = list(range(varMaxApiPages))
    json_array = [];
    for item in arr1:      
        jsonObejct = {"someID",item}
        json_array.append(jsonObejct)
    for item in json_array:
        print(item)

appendToArray(3)
```

---

The correct json array should look like this `[{"someID": 1},{"someID": 2},{"someID": 3}]`, we can achieve that. If you don’t want the colon, you can think of a way to replace it.
My debug result is as follows:
[image]

1. I declared 3 array type variables. Variable `res` is used to review the debug result.
   [image]
2. In Set variable1 activity, assign the value to it via `@range(1,3)`.
   [image]
3. Then Foreach the arr1.
   [image]
4. Inside Foreach activity, we can use Append variable activity, add expression `@json(concat('{"someID":',item(),'}'))`. It will convert json string to json Object and append to the array `jsonArray`.
   [image]
5. Outside Foreach activity, assign the value of array `jsonArray` to array `res` to review the result, you can omit this step and use array `jsonArray` directly.
   [image]

That's all.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The problem however is that the 'Set variable1' function in my case is already executed inside a ForEach loop. So we can't create another ForEach loop in there. Would you recommend to create an extra pipeline with your solution and call it after the Range function is called or is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi@BjörnBogers I have tried some but it seems that we cannot get returns from Execute Pipeline Activity. So I recommend you can use Azure function and write some such as Python script wo append some values to this Array.

Comment: [How can we improve Microsoft Azure Data Factory?](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/38690032-add-ability-to-customize-output-fields-from-execut)

Comment: I will build an Azure function app for it for now then. Thanks for your answers, I will also upvote the improvement link.